# How do I make the prev/next arrows work when I upload to my project?

Tags: html, css, slideshow

I am working on a pure css3 image slider for my website - The left/right arrow slide functionality works perfectly when I test it locally, but when I upload to my project - The arrows do not display right away (have to toggle radios) and then the left/right arrows, when clicked just return to slide number one. I tried making the selectors more unique as I thought they might be picking up something somewhere else in the site, but that didn't seem to work. Any Suggestions?

http://jsfiddle.net/jyka1mz8/

```
    <div class="wav-gal-slider-outer-container">

    <div class="wav-gal-container">
    <div class="wav-gal-slider-container">

    <input id="wav-gal-slider-1" type="radio" name="wav-gal-slider-radio-set" class="wav-gal-slider-selector1" checked="checked" />
    <label for="wav-gal-slider-1" class="wav-gal-slider-label-1"></label>

    <input id="wav-gal-slider-2" type="radio" name="wav-gal-slider-radio-set" class="wav-gal-slider-selector2" />
    <label for="wav-gal-slider-2" class="wav-gal-slider-label-2"></label>

    <input id="wav-gal-slider-3" type="radio" name="wav-gal-slider-radio-set" class="wav-gal-slider-selector3" />
    <label for="wav-gal-slider-3" class="wav-gal-slider-label-3"></label>

    <input id="wav-gal-slider-4" type="radio" name="wav-gal-slider-radio-set" class="wav-gal-slider-selector4" />
    <label for="wav-gal-slider-4" class="wav-gal-slider-label-4"></label>

    <input id="wav-gal-slider-5" type="radio" name="wav-gal-slider-radio-set" class="wav-gal-slider-selector5" />
    <label for="wav-gal-slider-5" class="wav-gal-slider-label-5"></label>


    <label for="wav-gal-slider-1" class="wav-gal-slider-prevnext wav-gal-slideshow-a1"></label>
    <label for="wav-gal-slider-2" class="wav-gal-slider-prevnext wav-gal-slideshow-a2"></label>
    <label for="wav-gal-slider-3" class="wav-gal-slider-prevnext wav-gal-slideshow-a3"></label>
    <label for="wav-gal-slider-4" class="wav-gal-slider-prevnext wav-gal-slideshow-a4"></label>
    <label for="wav-gal-slider-5" class="wav-gal-slider-prevnext wav-gal-slideshow-a5"></label>

    <div class="wav-gal-slider-background">
    <ul class="wav-gal-slides clearfix">
    <li><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/824x392/?text=one" alt="image01" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/824x392/?text=two" alt="image02" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/824x392/?text=three" alt="image03" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/824x392/?text=four" alt="image04" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/824x392/?text=five" alt="image05" /></li>
    </ul>
    </div><!-- wav-gal-slider-background -->

    </div><!-- wav-gal-slider-container -->


    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Im seeing nothing wrong in your example link

Comment: neither do I.. did u check if the css reference link is ok?